# Deleting "HostedZone created by Route53 Registrar"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have registered a domain using AWS and it has automatically created a Hosted Zone. The domain is not currently in use so is it safe to delete the Hosted Zone?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/DeleteHostedZone.html suggests that it should be fine as it only has an NS and an SOA record but I want to be sure that my domain registration won't be affected (I'm reasonably certain it won't but at the same time I'm not sure why I automatically get a Hosted Zone for $0.50 a month by default).

Comment: From your link: `If you want to keep your domain registration but you want to stop routing internet traffic to your website or web application, we recommend that you delete records in the hosted zone instead of deleting the hosted zone.` If you do not want to pay AWS, I recommend switching the name servers back to your registrars name servers if they support that.

Comment: Hm, I think it makes sense now - looks like if do domain registration with AWS you're locked into paying for a hosted zone regardless of whether you're doing DNS or DNS delegation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid the monthly charge for the hosted zone, you can transfer DNS service for the domain to a free DNS service. When you transfer DNS service, you have to update the name servers for the domain registration.

You can check the below link for transferring the DNS Service
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html

Comment: Thank you! The bit I was missing was to go to Registered domains and change the Name servers there, not just in Hosted zones.